# Is it more efficient to scan an array once against multiple predicates or multiple times against a single predicate

Tags: java, performance, sorting

I have an int array with 1000 elements. I need to extract the size of various sub-populations within the array (How many are even, odd, greater than 500, etc..).

I could use a for loop and a bunch of if statements to try add to a counting variable for each matching item such as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < someArray.length i++) {
    if(conditionA) sizeA++;
    if(conditionB) sizeB++;
    if(conditionC) sizeC++;
    ...
}
```

or I could do something more lazy such as:

```
Supplier<IntStream> ease = () -> Arrays.stream(someArray);
int sizeA = ease.get().filter(conditionA).toArray.length;
int sizeB = ease.get().filter(conditionB).toArray.length;
int sizeC = ease.get().filter(conditionC).toArray.length;
...
```

The benefit of doing it the second way seems to be limited to readability, but is there a massive hit on efficiency? Could it possibly be more efficient? I guess it boils down to is iterating through the array one time with 4 conditions always better than iterating through 4 times with one condition each time (assuming the conditions are independent). I am aware this particular example the second method has lots of additional method calls which I'm sure don't help efficiency any.

Comment: For performance, option 1 is better than latter

Comment: If you're playing with an array of 1000 elements, it doesn't really matter what you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preamble:

- As @Kayaman points out, for a small array (1000 elements) it probably doesn't matter.
- The correct approach to this kind of thing is to do the optimization **after** you have working code, and a working benchmark, and **after** you have profiled the code to see where the real hotspots are.

But assuming that this is worth spending effort on optimization, the first version is likely to be faster than the second version for a couple of reasons:

1. The overheads of incrementing and testing the index are only incurred once in the first version versus three times in the second one.
2. For an array that is too large to fit into the memory cache, the first version will entail fewer memory reads than the second one.  Since memory  access is typically a bottleneck (especially on a multi-core machine), this can be significant.
3. Streams add an extra performance overhead compared to simple iteration of an array.

Answer (score 3):

I did some time measuring with this code:

```
Random r = new Random();
int[] array = IntStream.generate(() -> r.nextInt(100)).limit(1000).toArray();
long odd = 0;
long even = 0;
long divisibleBy3 = 0;
long start = System.nanoTime();
//for (int i: array) {
//    if (i % 2 == 1) {
//        odd++;
//    }
//    if (i % 2 == 0) {
//       even++;
//    }
//    if (i % 3 == 0) {
//        divisibleBy3++;
//    }
//}
even = Arrays.stream(array).parallel().filter(x -> x % 2 == 0).toArray().length;
odd = Arrays.stream(array).parallel().filter(x -> x % 2 == 1).toArray().length;
divisibleBy3 = Arrays.stream(array).parallel().filter(x -> x % 3 == 0).toArray().length;
System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - start);
```

The above outputs a 8 digit number, usually around 14000000

If I uncomment the for loop and comment the streams, I get a 5 digit number as output, usually around 80000.

So the streams are slower in terms of execution time.

When the array size is bigger, though, the difference between streams and loops becomes smaller.

Comment: Streams are mostly useful on large amounts and operations. In this case the foreach will be more performant.

Comment: There problems with your benchmarking methodology.  For a start, the JIT compiler could optimize the loops away entirely.

Comment: @StephenC I admit it has problems. This is just a simple experiment.

Comment: @StephenC I used random numbers instead.

Comment: That's not the problem